# why my product result is 0 after multiplication

Tags: java

trying to get the result of multiplication
I am trying to find out the subarray product but the result is 0

---

```
public class SubArray {

        public void SubbArr(int arr[]) {
            int product = 1;
                for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                    for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++) {
                        for(int k=i;k<=j;k++) {
                            System.out.print(arr[k]+" ");
                            product = product*arr[k];
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            System.out.println("product is:"+product);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SubArray all = new SubArray();
            int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
            all.SubbArr(arr);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you exceeded the int max value, so you got 0

If you want to get the result you can use `BigDecimal`

```
    static void SubbArr(int arr[]) {
        BigDecimal product = new BigDecimal(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
                for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[k] + " ");
                    product = product.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(arr[k]));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("product is:" + product);
    }
```

More information: [BigDecimal Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Integer overflow is surely occurring, but that is not sufficient by itself to explain why the result is exactly 0.

Answer (score 1):

You multiplication result is overflowing. The multiplication result is too big for an int type to store. Though, I am not sure why it is showing 0. Maybe undefined behavior. You might want to use Java BigInt class for this one.

int is a 4 byte data type and its maximum value is 2,147,483,647. Calculate the multiplication result in a calculator, you will find that if you have a calculator nearby to calculate the large multiplication you have provided(though the array is small) is huge. Try passing a smaller array like {1,2,3}

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

The value of your `product` went beyond the maximum value an `int` can hold.

[`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) will be your rescue.

---

```
private static void SubbArr(int[] arr) {
    BigInteger product = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;i ++) {
        for(int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            for(int k = i ; k <= j; k++) {
                System.out.print(arr[k] + " ");
                product = product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(arr[k]));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("product is: " + product);
}
```

**Side note:** I have changed your code style to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is computing not just one subarray product, but the product of *all* contiguous, nonempty subarray products.  You don't appear to have considered how large the result may be, so lets start by counting the subarrays.  That's not so hard: there are 6 of length 1, 5 of length 2, etc., ending with 1 of length 6.  That's 21 factors, or 20 if we disregard the one that is identically 1.  There are only 32 bits in an `int`, and one is a sign bit, so that should already get your hackles up.

In fact, counting 2s (including those in 4s and 6s) in the various subarrays reveals that **the product you are computing is a multiple of 2<sup>40</sup>, which is why the multiplication overflows to an `int` result with all bits zero** -- they are the 32 least-significant bits of the arithmetic result.

The result is also a multiple of 3<sup>20</sup> and of 5<sup>10</sup>.  These factors are each larger than 2<sup>20</sup>, so your overall product exceeds 2<sup>80</sup>.  Even a `long` cannot accommodate that; to compute an exact result, your best bet is probably a `BigInteger`.